# Bash Script to find/sort/move images/duplicate images from USB drive

Tags: bash, duplicates

Ultimately, I'm looking to create a script that allows me to plug in a usb drive with lots of jpegs on it & copy them over to a folder on my hard drive. 
So in the process of copying I am looking to hash check them, record dupes to a file, copy only 1 of the identical files while renaming any files of the same name that are NOT identical (ie same hash) but copying them over too.

Answer (score 0):

Such script will copy and rename each file using their md5sum:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e  # to quit immediately on uncatched error 

#fill the next variables to your needs
sourcedir="..."
destdir="..."

# U may add more extension (tiff, gif ...) 
iregex=".*\.\(jpeg\|jpg\|png\)"

mkdir -p "$destdir"

find "$sourcedir" -type f -iregex "$iregex" | while read file ; do
    cp -v "$file" "$destdir/$(md5sum "$file" | cut -d" " -f1).${file##*.}"
done
```

But if u want to keep some original name (assuming their name are not a fantasy one made by some camera) , It will be more complicated...